# How to code Upper_bound STL function to find the position of the element greater than given element?

Tags: c++, stl

I want to write a code to find the upper bound stl function which returns the POSITION of element greater than the given element.
I have done that for lower bound but couldnt do it for upper bound and also i dont want to use other stl functions to find the position.

Code:

```
int lowerBound(int a[], int n, int key)
{
    int low = 0, high = n-1, mid, pos = -1;
    while(low <= high)
    {
        mid = (low + high)/2;
        if(a[mid] < key)
        {
            low = mid+1;
        }

        else
        {
            pos = mid;
            high = mid-1;
        }

    }
    return pos;
}
```

Comment: Well, the easy way out is to simply use your existing function that finds the lower bound, then increment the result, if necessary.

Comment: The input `a[]` is sorted in ascending order ?

Comment: @Rishi ya you can assume that

Comment: @SamVarshavchik what if all the inputs are same?
like a[] = {1,1,1,1,1}
your method gives pos = 2 (1 based index) but it is not so.
Also if i search for next element the solution becomes O(n)

Comment: Simply replace `a[mid] < key` with `!(key < a[mid])`  (or, in case of plain integers, `a[mid] <= key`, but in the more general case you may only have `<` operator available).